# What's the max value for the Float data type in teradata?

Tags: types, teradata

```
CREATE TABLE "CMCAPACITY"("CMPATH" VARCHAR(4000)NOT NULL,
        "CAPACITY" FLOAT(128), "USAGE" SMALLINT NOT NULL);
```

I am getting "Precision error in FLOAT type constant or during implicit conversions."

Comment: belongs on stackoverflow (or maybe serverfault)

Comment: Just wait for 2 more people with 3000+ rep to flag it for moving and it will happen automatically for you.

Comment: Or, try posting here: http://teradataquestions.com/

Comment: What precision do you need for CAPACITY? Can you give some sample values?

Comment: @lins314159 upto 25 digits of scale and 5 digits of precision

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try going with just FLOAT without anything afterwards. The [Teradata data types documentation](http://www.teradataforum.com/teradata_pdf/b035-1101-061a_3.pdf) doesn't show any use for brackets. Testing on the database also indicates that it's not taken into account, as they can store the same values and result in the same column metadata.

Answer (score 1):

Maximum  precision for float data type in Teradata is 54.

For example:

```
CREATE TABLE "CMCAPACITY" (
        "CAPACITY" FLOAT(54)
);
```

Comment: There's no precision for a FLOAT in Teradata, i would expect an error message for FLOAT(whatevver). This maximum of 54 is just strange, seems to be parsed and then simply ignored :-)